# PhpStorm shows undefined class but I can use this class

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, undefined

I'm creating my first project in Symfony and PhpStorm shows me something like this "Undefined class 'AbstractController'" or "Undefined class 'JsonResponse'". I tried everything I found on Google but nothing help...
Do you have any ideas?

[image]

I tried below things:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- `idea.properties` -> change `idea.max.intellisense.fillesize=2500` to `5000`
- Include path
- CLI interpreter

Comment: 1) *"change idea.max.intellisense.fillesize"* This has nothing to do with the issue (PHP files are much-much smaller than that. 2) Considering the lack of other info (that may play a role here) I suggest the following: 1) Check `idea.log` for any possible related exception (`Help | Show Log in XXX`) 2) Disable ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restart the IDE, let it reindex -- any better? 3) Use `File | Repair IDE...` and follow all steps until it gets better.

Comment: Can also try the following first: 1) close the IDE 2) Go to the project root folder, locate there the `.idea` subfolder (Project config is stored here) and then backup & delete it. 3) Now launch the IDE and if it did not open the same project automatically, just use `File | Open` and point to the project root -- the IDE will make a fresh project from those files. If it helps -- could be something wrong with the project config files (corruption / missing / old info etc) or user misconfiguration somewhere.

Comment: It's just had to guess where the issue might be without knowing "seemingly not important/unrelated details" and a single basic screenshot only.

Comment: seems to be something with autoloader. (1) install symfony plugin for phpstorm (2) check psr-4 namespace in composer.json. (3) did you install all the vendors? is `composer install` running. (4) try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: First of all thanks guys for quick response! After @rickroyce hint, I managed to solve it. The issue was with composer. I upgrade version of PHP to ^8.2 and later on composer install and composer update and issue gone. Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe it was because I had PHP version ^8.2 in container but locally I had 8.1 and also I installed plugins for symfony